# SSD lifetime when using in development

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, development, lifespan

I just bought Samsung 850 Pro 1TB SSD to speed up my laptop. I moved all my virtual machines to SSD so they will boot very fast. The only thing that I was not aware before buying an SSD is that it has limitations of write cycles. I use one of my VM's(Win7 x64) for C++ development and every time during recompilation of the project around 1GB of files were been overwritten. I assume that everyday usage with 100GB writes will be OK: http://www.anandtech.com/show/8239/update-on-samsung-850-pro-endurance-vnand-die-size

But anyway I would like to hear from other developers who uses SSD in their development machines, how long are you using your SSD's, approximately how much writes per day you have and are there any problems after long usage? Maybe I should move my VM's to HDD(I have another 1TB HDD in second slot)? Because the difference during development only in programs opening time but actual build time is the same as on HDD.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer myself and I use SSDs almost every day to do my daily programming/compiling with them. I never had any problems with my current one that I got 2-3 years ago.

Comment: Thanks! Also I found this article where they tested 6 SSD's during 18 months of heavy usage(more than 4TB writes per day), you can check results by the links in the bottom of the article:
http://techreport.com/review/24841/introducing-the-ssd-endurance-experiment/5